# Getting velocity error at statup "VM_global_library.vm"

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I am using Velocity with Spring.
But in Eclipse console I get this error. My code works fine, but I want to know how to fix it.

ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'VM_global_library.vm' in any resource loader.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like it is a harmless message. From the [Velocity Documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.5/developer-guide.html), if this file is present, Velocity loads this up as a location of global macros. I believe you can override the behaviour by resetting or overriding the value of the below property.

`velocimacro.library=`

Comment: which file r u talking bout , i have only added jar file in spring eclipse .

Answer (score 4):

We used to get this all the time. It's just looking for the global velocity macro library. You can just put an empty file with that name at the root of your velocity config directory or somewhere else accessible by your resource loaders. If I remember correctly its a file for you to create your own global macros... can be empty.

You may be able to disable that feature in the config, but I think the version we were using at the time did not have any way to turn off that checking.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your Velocity version.  Or, just create an empty template of that name.

Comment: can you give me the link for jar file of latest velocity . i could not find it

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you should go directly to the [Apache Velocity downloads page](http://velocity.apache.org/download.cgi) and get the updated engine (1.7) and tools (2.0). Using the link above was less than helpful, but when I updated all the jars for velocity (including the 2 velocity jars and the 3 tools jars), this error finally went away. It's such a tiny thing but it's bothered me for ages.