# JMeter - Velocity JSR223 script can't use JMeter variables/environment

Tags: java, jmeter, velocity, jsr223, jmeter-5.0

I'm able to load [Velocity as language to JSR223](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686685/jmeter-add-velocity-language-to-jsr-223-sampler) in JMeter 4/5,

I added `velocity-engine-core-2.0.jar` and `velocity-engine-scripting-2.0.jar` which include velocity in JSR223 languages list,

(Tried also with latest velocity [2.1 versions](http://velocity.apache.org/download.cgi#engine))

The problem that any text given is ignored, even if I put invalid syntax it doesn't throw any exception (as in other languages), or use `vars`, `log`,...

It seems that script isn't executed, how can I execute velocity JSR223 script? do I need to add configurations or jars?
Or is there some JMeter/Java restrictions for velocity?

Tried for example:

```
log.info("Hello Velocity");
vars.put("a","Hello Velocity");
System.out.println("Hello Velocity");
NoExists.out.println("Hello Velocity");
```

It seems that I have [velocity runtime dependencies](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/dependencies.html)

> slf4j-api  1.7.25  Yes Yes Yes you'll also need an slf4j binding at runtime
>
> commons-lang   3.5 Yes Yes Yes

library contains `slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar` `commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar` and added `slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar` to default JMeter library

Log:

```
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Preparing class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting scriptLanguage=velocity
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting parameters=
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting filename=
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting cacheKey=false
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting script=log.info("Hello Velocity");
vars.put("a","Hello Velocity");
System.out.println("Hello Velocity");
NoExists.out.println("Hello Velocity");
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Initializing Velocity, Calling init()...
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 TRACE o.a.velocity: *****************************
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Starting Apache Velocity v2.0
2019-06-05 11:48:05,739 TRACE o.a.velocity: RuntimeInstance initializing.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Default Properties resource: org/apache/velocity/runtime/defaults/velocity.properties
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 TRACE o.a.v.loader: ResourceManager initializing: class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 DEBUG o.a.velocity: ResourceLoader instantiated: org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 TRACE o.a.v.l.file: FileResourceLoader: initialization starting.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 DEBUG o.a.v.l.file: FileResourceLoader: adding path '.'
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 TRACE o.a.v.l.file: FileResourceLoader: initialization complete.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 DEBUG o.a.velocity: initialized (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl) with class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap cache map.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 TRACE o.a.v.loader: Default ResourceManager initialization complete.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,741 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Stop
2019-06-05 11:48:05,742 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Define
2019-06-05 11:48:05,742 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Break
2019-06-05 11:48:05,742 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Evaluate
2019-06-05 11:48:05,742 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Macro
2019-06-05 11:48:05,742 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse
2019-06-05 11:48:05,742 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Include
2019-06-05 11:48:05,742 DEBUG o.a.velocity: Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach
2019-06-05 11:48:05,743 DEBUG o.a.v.parser: Created '20' parsers.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,743 TRACE o.a.v.macro: initialization starting.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,743 DEBUG o.a.v.macro: "velocimacro.library" is not set. Trying default library: VM_global_library.vm
2019-06-05 11:48:05,743 DEBUG o.a.v.macro: Default library not found.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,743 DEBUG o.a.v.macro: allowInline = true: VMs can be defined inline in templates
2019-06-05 11:48:05,743 DEBUG o.a.v.macro: allowInlineToOverride = false: VMs defined inline may NOT replace previous VM definitions
2019-06-05 11:48:05,743 DEBUG o.a.v.macro: allowInlineLocal = false: VMs defined inline will be global in scope if allowed.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,744 DEBUG o.a.v.macro: autoload off: VM system will not automatically reload global library macros
2019-06-05 11:48:05,744 TRACE o.a.v.macro: Velocimacro: initialization complete.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,744 TRACE o.a.velocity: RuntimeInstance successfully initialized.
2019-06-05 11:48:05,744 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController
```

**EDIT**

It seems that Invalid velocity context can raise an error,

e.g. for calling not exists velocity variable `$a`

> ```
> 2019-06-05 12:39:28,804 DEBUG o.a.v.rendering: Null reference [template '<unknown>', line 2, column 7]: $a cannot be resolved.
> ```

But the problem remains that JMeter can't use the velocity variable in its context

**EDIT**

workaround is to add velocity LogTool (velocity-tools-generic-3.0.jar) and use `$log`

```
$log.debug( "Hello Velocity");
```

But can't use JMeter variable as

```
$log.debug( "Hello " + vars.get("a"));
```

Comment: Are you checking log (Options -> Log Viewer) in GUI? Do you have correct log level (Options -> Log Level)?

Comment: @lojza yes, also `OUT` not working `System.out.println`, and invalid syntax is ignored instead of exception

Comment: check your log: `"velocimacro.library" is not set` and `Default library not found`

Comment: It seems irrelevant when check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313470/getting-velocity-error-at-statup-vm-global-library-vm if not what is your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas :-(

Comment: Have you inquired with the JMeter teamt hat Velocity 2.0+ works with JMeter 5?

Comment: @michael-o JSR223 is open for all scripting languages, velocity is used for JMeter docs and There's an enhancenent to add it https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63484

Comment: So you should test without JMeter through JSR 223 only, if that does not work. Then there is a bug in Velocity.

Comment: @michael-o velocity **can** be executed and log using its `$logTool` inside JMeter, but it can't use JMeter variables, meaning both works, but the integration is lacking

Comment: This must be then a JMeter issue.

Comment: @Michael-O see my answer, In Velocity need to add `$` in front of the bindings variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, in Velocity you need to add `$` in front of your context variable name,

So instead of `vars` use `$vars`:

```
$log.debug( "Hello " + $vars.get("a"));
```

There's an enhancement to [add Velocity to JMeter as JSR223 language](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63484), You can [vote](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=63484#vote_63484)